# Обнуление строки string

Tags: c++

Для того, что бы сделать строку **временно** пустой, я использую

```
string m = "text";
...
m = "";
...
if (m == "")
...
```

А есть более традиционный и правильный вариант, или разницы особо нет?

Comment: Какой смысл вы вкладываете во "временность" опустошения строки? А в не временном случае должно быть какое-то другое решение?

Comment: @Kromster что бы сразу отсеять предложения о полном удалении переменной через деструктор.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно еще так.

```
m.clear();
if (m.empty())
```

Comment: Так даже лучше. `clear()` делает одну-единственную операцию — обнуляет поле длины строки. А исходно предлагаемое присваивание `""` вызывает попытку скопировать строковый литерал (хоть и состоящий из одного нуль-терминатора).

Comment: @Arhad у `clear` сложность линейная, более того: *"Effects: Behaves as if the function calls: `erase(begin(), end());`"*

Comment: @alexolut, libstdc++ так не думает. [`clear()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00770_source.html#l00795) вызывает [`_M_mutate()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00771_source.html#l00468), передавая ей исходную длину строки и нули в качестве новой длины и смещения. Далее, единственное, что вызывает `_M_mutate()` с такими аргументами — это [`_M_set_length_and_sharable()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00770_source.html#l00201), помечающая буфер общим и выполняющая `this->_M_length = __n;`. Получаем константную сложность.

Answer (score 0):

```
string MyString("Hello World");

cout << "Source string: ";
cout << MyString << endl;

MyString.clear();

cout << "String after cleaning: {";
cout << MyString << "}" << endl;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Также имеет смысл приводить самодостаточный код, чтобы можно было его запустить у себя сразу. Т.е. не хватает`main`, `std::` и заголовочных файлов/модулей